# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: redirect, login, permissions

After long time am here,I have one question.

I Installed my wordpress in localhost and i moved to live,while i forgot the admin password,so i reset it by phpmyadmin(using md5).now i try to login by using with correct password it's redirect to [This page](http://www.cairncroftmanagement.com/wp-admin/profile.php) and shows **You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.**

please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Occasionally I've seen issues doing a manual reset of the password if salts have changed, or if there was an issue with the account before the reset. Some things to try:

- Are you sure you reset the password for the main admin account, usually ID #1? Trivial, I know, but has happened to me in the past.
- Try using the [Emergency Password Reset Script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Using_the_Emergency_Password_Reset_Script), as it works a little better than a manual reset.
- Try changing the salts in wp-config.php and reset the password again, see if it clears out some cookie issues you may be having. Most likely your problem can be traced to cookie issues if it is accepting the password but not letting you in. Clear all your cookies out as well.

Answer (score 1):

Also, review this useful codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the codex articles for resetting your password are from 2005 and more than likely don't apply as WP doesn't use MD5.

The most simple way of doing it would be to simply execute the `wp_hash_password()` function and put that directly in to the database. I suggest setting up a simple script like so:

```
<?php
include('wp-load.php');

echo wp_hash_password( 'password' );
```

Put this in your webroot (with the other WP files), copy and paste the output into your row in the database. Delete the file when you're done.

Comment: Except that MD5 hashed passwords will work if you need to manually change the password... maybe they changed it back in recent times? :P